# Proper Gridview Alternative?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

What is the proper alternative to Gridview in ASP.NET?

By proper I mean highly customizable, css and JQuery friendly.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) fits that bill.